# How do i change the Location in the Header?

Tags: php

I don't know why my header isn't working, can you help me?
Basically during all my page, I've been using header **("Location: ../../../login.php");** to redirect to login if they haven't logged in, but now, in my script where I search in database if the user exist and that, i try to redirect them to the welcome page, but in reality it redirects to the first login, not matter what i do, it doesn't work.

```
if($row['idUsuario'] == $_POST['username'] AND $row['password'] == $_POST['password'] AND  $row['nivel']==2)
{
  $_SESSION['sesion_coordinador']="creada";
    $_SESSION['coordinador']=$id_usuario;
    header ("Location: coordinador-login.php");
exit;

}
```

I've tried using ob_start();and ob_flush(); but at this point, i don't know what i'm doing.

I appreciate your help!

Comment: **Danger**: "Not hashing at all" is [an unsuitable hashing algorithm](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php); you need to [take better care](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet) of your users' passwords.

Comment: It isn't clear what is happening here. Is the `if` block being entered? Is the `header` method being called? Is the client being redirected to `coordinador-login.php`? On the path you expect? Is that where you want them to be redirected to? Does it then get redirected from there to somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, i've tried a var_dump($_SESSION); and actually change the values and all, it's just the header that doesn't work, it's like it only reedirect to login.php

Comment: And thank you for the hashing comment, i've forgot that at all<3

Comment: `where idUsuario = ? and nivel = 2` would be better than selecting all records and iterating over results.

Comment: Ok, i'm gonna change it, Thank u<3

Comment: I've fixed it. I changed my sql statement to **where idUsuario = ? and nivel = 2** instead of iterate all of the records. I don't have a clue how that fixed the Header, but it did. Thank you for your help!<3

Answer (score 0):

if you are outputting any information before header(Location: ...), remove that. then location header wont work as it is already sent.
also maybe this may work?

```
if($row['idUsuario'] == $_POST['username'] AND $row['password'] == $_POST['password'] AND  $row['nivel']==2)
{
    $_SESSION['sesion_coordinador']="creada";
    $_SESSION['coordinador']=$id_usuario;
    header("Location: /coordinador-login.php");
    exit;
}
```

Comment: I didn't output anything before, but i've tried your code and it's funny tho, if i put /coordinador-login.php it sends me to the begining of my path like localhost/coordinador-login.php, but if i put the entire path, it doubles the path, like localhost/../../../../../../ and if i quit all, it sends me to login.php.

Comment: is there any intermediate redirects such as page redirects to /blablaabla/coordinador-login.php and it redirects to something else? maybe the issue is from a different file

Comment: I've fixed it. I changed my sql statement to **where idUsuario = ? and nivel = 2** instead of iterate all of the records. I dont have a clue how that fixed the Header, but it did. Thank you for your help!<3

Comment: n‪o‪ ‪p‪r‪o‪b‪l‪em!‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‪